# Cloudant keeps prompting for authentication even with pouchDB synch started with correct creds, and CORS enabled

Tags: cors, ibm-cloud, pouchdb, cloudant

Cloudant keeps prompting (Modal window) for authentication even though pouchDB synch was started with correct credentials in the url, and CORS is enabled on the remote database.

Are the initial credentials not cached for the remote db during instantiation?

The weird thing is that if the modal window is cancelled out of the way the new docs still come down through replication...

Comment: You're using this format for your API call?`https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE_NAME`

Emphasizing `https`

Comment: From my colleague Glynn Bird, "PouchDB needs the ability to write checkpoint documents to the Cloudant side to track state. So it needs a minimum of _reader and _replicator access to do that. (That would explain why data is getting replicated. Only the checkpoints are getting 403'd.)"

Comment: @bradnoble indeed I am using the https, which I think is mandatory in bluemix. the exact code: 

var remoteCouch = https://userxxxbluemix:passwordxxx@xxxbluemix.cloudant.com/' + dbName;

db.sync(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);

I also tried:

db.replicate.to(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);  
db.replicate.from(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);

But according to the API doc they are equivalent.

Comment: I gave Reader/Writer/Admin/Replicator permissions to that user for testing, but good to know, I will keep reader and replicator for production.

Comment: Did that solve the problem? If so, I'll make that the answer and we close this out.

Comment: Thanks @bradnoble, close but no cigare, it seems that the issue might be with pouchDB for now though, the _bulk_get request is not passing the original creds in the header as it does for the other requests, hence throwing a 401. I opened an issue on the pouchDb GitHub, you can read more about it here [link](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4748). You can close from a Cloudant perspective, or leave open and I will update when there is a resolution. Cheers.

Comment: OK, please update here when you have more. Thanks.

Comment: This issue has been resolved as of 5.2.0 @bradnoble can you close?

Answer (score 0):

Per @Thierry's latest update, this issue has been resolved with PouchDB 5.2.0:

http://pouchdb.com/2016/01/13/pouchdb-5.2.0-a-better-build-system-with-rollup.html